# how read pdf layers and add to another page using itextsharp?

Tags: c#, itext

How can I read PDF layers and add them to another page using `iTextSharp`?

I want to copy layers from one PDF page and move them to another PDF page in C#.

I've tried reading from a PDF layer from one page, but I am unable to copy that layer.

```
var document = new Document();

FileStream outfile = new FileStream(outPutFilePath, FileMode.Create);

var writer = new PdfCopy(document, outfile);

document.Open();


foreach (var fileName in filesPath)
{
    var reader = new PdfReader(fileName);
    PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outfile);

    Dictionary<String, PdfLayer> layers = stamper.GetPdfLayers();
    //PdfLayer layer = layers.get("Nested layer 1");
    //layer.setOn(false);

    for (var i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
    {
        var page = writer.GetImportedPage(reader, i);
        page.ContentTagged = true;
        writer.AddPage(page);

    }
    stamper.Close();

    reader.Close();
}
writer.Close();

document.Close();
```

Comment: Please provide some code. Show us what you've done already.

Comment: Here i want to merge pdf files with layers.suppose i  have pdf  one, it has two layers(a,b) and i have another pdf file ,this pdf have one page this has 3 layers(c,d,e).  now i want merge and out like  page one(a,b layers)  ,page two has (c,d,e) layers.like this way is it possible?

Comment: I would assume you should use `PdfCopy` instead of `PdfStamper` and then create document-wide layer information to the merged document.

Comment: above code i able to copying from one page to another page but unable copying layers,please provide sample code